# Using fake datasets to optimize a model

Tags: machine-learning, synthetic-data

I have a machine learning application I'm working on that will make predictions based on data about retail stores.  Problem is, any data collected by BI regarding the performance of a given retail store is highly guarded.  Is it feasible for me to work with a mock dataset and still get a good idea of my model's performance on real data?  For instance, could I just pick a function describing the true behavior of the system, add a zero mean random error to each response, and generate data points?  Is it common to work with fake data in cases where real data is not available?

Comment: Can you be more specific about your goals?  If you're working on this project as a way to learn some machine learning techniques, then generating a simulated dataset sounds fine. Likewise if you need to develop a demo version of a product in order to get investment to develop the real thing, for example.  But there's no reason at all to think that a model that does well with simulated data would perform well on real data.

Comment: Andrew Gelman has been quite vocal over the years he's been publishing his blog about using fake or simulated data for model calibration and validation... see here ... http://andrewgelman.com/2009/09/04/fake-data_simul/. It's also worth noting that simulations first took on great significance in the post-WWII era after the research methods developed for the Manhattan Project (the US project that built the first nuclear bombs) received wider dissemination and publication. So, using simulations is a well-established, best practice.